# Cannot explicitly update values of @LastModifiedBy and @LastModifiedDate annotated columns of an entity in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using the following Hibernate Entity in one of my Spring boot applications.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "description")
  private String description;

  ...
}
```

`AbstractAuditingEntity` is as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @CreatedBy
  @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private String createdBy;

  @CreatedDate
  @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

  @LastModifiedBy
  @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
  @JsonIgnore
  private String lastModifiedBy;

  @LastModifiedDate
  @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
  ...
  }
```

In all the existing flows the `lastModifiedBy` and `lastModifiedDate` are getting populated correctly.

Now, in a new flow, I am syncing the above entity from another system and I would like to update the `lastModifiedDate` and `lastModifiedBy` values explicitly. I have tried the below update query in order to update these two fields, but it's not working.

```
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
@Query("update Student u set " +
      "u.lastModifiedBy = :lastModifiedBy, " +
      "u.lastModifiedDate = :lastModifiedDate " +
      "where u.id = :id")
  void updateLastModifiedInformation(@Param("lastModifiedBy") String lastModifiedBy,
                                            @Param("lastModifiedDate") Instant lastModifiedDate,
                                            @Param("id") String id);
```

Even after the update, I see the `lastModifiedDate` and `lastModifiedBy` columns are getting populated with the current date and currently signed-in user respectively, which I don't want.

I am not getting any clue as to how to make this work.

**EDIT**:

After the suggestion in the comment, I tried the native query as well as follows, but still the same:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update Student u set " +
      "u.last_modified_by = :lastModifiedBy, " +
      "u.last_modified_date = :lastModifiedDate " +
      "where u.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
  void updateLastModifiedInformation(@Param("lastModifiedBy") String lastModifiedBy,
                                            @Param("lastModifiedDate") Instant lastModifiedDate,
                                            @Param("id") String id);
```

Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: I think this will be possible only with native query, otherwise the auditing will always be called when working with JPA.

Comment: @bilak I tried the native query also as I have edited the OP, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your question, and here is one possible solution.

First define `setLastModifiedDate` method in `AbstractAuditingEntity`:

```
public void setLastModifiedDate(Instant lastModifiedDate) {
  this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
}
```

By calling `student.setLastModifiedDate(date)`, you will be able to set the last modified date of your choice and save to `StudentRepo`, which I tested with the following method at `StudentServ`:

```
public void testUpdateLastModifiedDate(String id, Student student, Instant instant){
  student.setId(id);
  student.setLastModifiedDate(instant);
  studentRepo.save(student);
}
```

The `lastModifiedDate` would be updated to the `instant` of your input.

The `lastModifiedBy` field should be handled similarly.

Hope it is of help.

EDIT:

Further to the modified query, the following should be more similar to what you want to achieve:

```
public void update(String id, Instant lastModifiedDate, String lastModifiedBy){
  Optional<Student> opt = studentRepo.findById(id);
  if(opt.isEmpty()) return;

  Student student = opt.get();
  student.setLastModifiedDate(lastModifiedDate);
  student.setLastModifiedBy(lastModifiedBy);
  studentRepo.save(student);
}
```